# como hash un contraseña en Django

Tags: python, django, registro

#tengo un formulario de registro el cual quiero que se hashee la pasword pero no puedo editar el formulario para obtener la constraseña hashearla para luego setearla y se vea de diferente forma en base de datos

```py
from xml.parsers.expat import model
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'perfil de {self.user.username}'

class Usuario(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tipo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

formModel

```py
from pyexpat import model
from django import forms
from .models import Usuario
class FormUsuario(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=200,label="Username")
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=200,label="Email")
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=200,label=" password" ,widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    public_options=[
        (1,'fisio'),
        (0,'customer')
    ]
    tipo =forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=public_options
        )
   
    class Meta:
        model=Usuario
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'tipo']
        field="__all__"
```

aqui en el view no he podido editar el campo password

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormUsuario(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = FormUsuario()
    context ={'form':form}
    return render(request, 'register.html',context )
```

Answer (score 0):

El usuario tendría que venir de AbstractUser y no de models.Model.
Luego en el save() pueder utilizar: self.set_password(self.password)